# Saving float as it is using Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, decimal, tofixed

Is there anyway to save a float and preserving its decimal place at the same time ? e.g.

1.50 will be saved as 1.50 instead of 1.5.

I've tried solution such as toFixed, but they are returning me a variable of typeof string.

Comment: then you should use String instead and convert it to float if needed to do some calculation

Comment: Numbers are numbers; they have no concept of how many trailing zeroes were parsed.

Comment: Then no; if you need to present `1.50` use the string, for calculations `1.5` and `1.50` are exactly the same.

Comment: `1.5` is exactly the same as `1.50`, in a sense, so it's already doing what you want. Concern with maintenance of "significant digits" must be done at the binary digit level anyway.

Comment: @Pointy The value of `1.5` as a _float (32-bit)_ written as bytes is `0x00 0x00 0xC0 0x3F`, which doesn't have any bits dedicated to number of trailing zeros.

Comment: @PaulS. yes I know - I meant that the values are *conceptually* the same.

Comment: Alright, because I tried a couple of solutions, thought there would be some solution out here. Thank you all so much for the responses :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, you would have to turn it into a string if you want to preserve those zeros.